# Restore mysql database with some columns content enclosed by " and another not

Tags: mysql, restore

We have to restore a database in MySQL but some columns have content enclosed by " and another not like in this sample:

```
00.168.93.70,null,ES,0,htc,33a48a1515b20691,"htc;HTC One (REL4.4.2)",m7,53e4b0f1e733a4a95e,-Free-2.1.0.6.f,4.4.2,unknown,13,"Internet app",com.app.android.free.debug,null,"HTC One",test@gmail.com,"31.5000,34.7500",APA91bE1E-7-tO1fgbYCs5kbiUapri1zm5Bda5ehyXmTgTOabx5GQHprbYhfB62w0BgdJ7Nbe3qevehFmhCmGXwArSkCr8qpyjoL_WIGq7IA0tsyC4pmpxT0RO9gJ2K3ErfaMQevHviUR4ZJrm_,"en_EN,zh_CN"
unknown,unknown,unknown,0,htc,33a48515b20691,"htc;HTC One (REL4.4.2)",m7,5385a31e733a4a95f,Free-2.1.0.6.f,4.4.2,unknown,0,unknown,com.app.android.free.debug,unknown,"HTC One",test@gmail.com,unknown,APA9zm5Bda5ehyXmTgTOabx5GQHprbYhfB62w0BgdJ7Nbe3qeveAtIxxi0X3mCr8qpyjoL_WIGq7IA0tsyC4pmpxT0RO9gJ2K3ErfaMQevHviUR4ZJrm,
```

How Can I restore it properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a problem?  The quoting is usually "optional".  Or did you need the quotes to be kept with the columns?

You can control which case you have by including/excluding the `ENCLOSED BY` or `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` clause in `LOAD DATA`.

> If the input values are not necessarily enclosed within quotation marks, use OPTIONALLY before the ENCLOSED BY option.
>
> If not empty, the FIELDS [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY and FIELDS ESCAPED BY values must be a single character.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'x:/folder/filename.csv'
INTO TABLE tablename ( field1,    -- load value into the field directly
                       field2,    -- when it is enclosed, d-quotes are saved
                       ... , 
                       @dummyN,   -- load value with wrapping into UDV
                       ...)
SET fieldN = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM @dummyN) -- extract value from UDV and store into the field
```

This allows to remove d-quote chars when they are wrappers and store when they're a part of value, if this occures at the same time (for different fields).